# Calculating the one-sided limits $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2-x}\right)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{x^2-x}\right)$.

Tags: limits

I have this here two limits (results courtesy of WA):

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{x^2-x}\right) = 1$$

and

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{x^2-x}\right) = -1$$

If I go to solve the first one, I get:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{x^2-x}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{\left(0^-\right)^2-0^-}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{0-0^-}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{-0^-}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{0^+}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\tanh\left(+\infty\right) = 1$$

and the second one I get:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{x^2-x}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{\left(0^+\right)^2-0^+}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{0-0^+}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{-0^+}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\tanh\left(\frac{{1}}{0^-}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\tanh\left(-\infty\right) = -1$$

I guess this is right, but I'm not sure if I got the right result because it's right, or by accident. I'm assuming I have some mistakes above that cancel each other out.

The bottom line is, I 'm guessing here when manipulating $0^-$ and $0^+$.

When you square them, they both go to $0^+$, right? What about addition/subtraction?
How do you add/subtract $0^-$ and $0^+$? What do you get?

Could I just take out the sign of the zero from exponent and put it in front of it?

Comment: What is "th"???

Comment: I'm guessing hyperbolic tangent, some indicate it like that

Comment: Yep. I'll clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\tanh z=\frac{1-e^{-2z}}{1+e^{-2z}}$$

Now, as $x\to 0^{+}$, we have $z:=\frac{1}{x(x-1)}\to-\infty$, so

$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\tanh z=\lim_{z\to-\infty}\frac{1-e^{-2z}}{1+e^{-2z}}=-1$$

by, say, L'Hopital's rule at the last step.

The other computation, for $x\to0^{-}$, is similar.

Comment: Let's forget the tan. Imagine if it were just the fraction. How do I manipulate zeros?

Comment: Don't think of it as "manipulating zeros." What exactly is your question? You seem to be asking why $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{1}{x^2-x}=-\infty$. It is because $\frac{1}{x^2-x}=\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$, and clearly this expression is negative when $x>0$.

Comment: You don't want to "manipulate the zeros." You want to factor $x^2-x$ as $x(x-1)$. Then $x-1\to-1$ whether $x\to0^+$ or $x\to0^-$. So you will either get $0^-\cdot(-1)$ or $0^+\cdot(-1)$.